# How to arrange in order from smaller to biggest : $2^{120}$, $3^{72}$, $17^{30}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, exponentiation

Comparison between exponents of different base and power.

Answer (score 4):

### Hint:

$$17^{30}>16^{30}=2^{4\cdot30}=2^{120}$$

Answer (score 4):

$2^{120}=(2^{10})^{12}=1024^{12}>729^{12}=(3^6)^{12}=3^{72} \tag{1}$

In general, **first take the divisors of lcm of powers and compare** or first compare and then take the divisors of lcm of powers, whichever makes comparison easier.

I have use the technique mentioned in **bold**, while Roman83 has used the latter.

From $(1)$ and Roman83's answer, we get

> $$17^{30} > 2^{120} > 3^{72}$$

Comment: A good idea and a good explanation (+1). If the OP cannot do $3^6$ by mental arithmetic, then they might want go all the way to the gcd of the exponents, here $\gcd(120,72)=24$. So
$2^5=32>3^3=27$ and therefore
$$2^{120}=(2^5)^{24}>(3^3)^{24}=3^{72}.$$